# Should I use CMS

Tags: web-applications, content-management-system, payment, user-management, oauth-2.0

I'm a undergraduate, new to everything, I'm thinking of creating a website that logins, registers a user and has password recovery options.
Also there will be options for **Oauth2** through google,etc...

And it will accept **Payments** for certain set of services.

Since I've to deal with payments, should I use CMS like Joomla, Drupal,etc for the **security purpose** and **faster setup**. Or there is something else for this puporse.

I'm looking for something like Magento does just add zip and provide database username and password and user management is done in minutes with full encryption of database.

P.S. Anything Hard or Easy will work for me and it MUST be **FREE** and Language is not the barrier...

Comment: everything you mention is relatively easy with asp.net MVC. The Oauth2 is actually built into the template project. And as I understand it, it's free for organizations under a certain size.

Comment: CMS or content managed system is for manipulate the content of a page from a user interface. For dealing with payments/security you don't want a CMS. Login/Reg, Payments, Google auth all those can be done through a normal web app..

Answer (score 0):

First choose a platform, language by analysing which will be efficient for your case. Then go for frameworks etc.

CMS is used when you need to provide real time changes to your website without doing any changes in your project. Not many applications need that.

If you choose Java/J2EE as your platform, almost everything you want will be open source.

You can go through basic tutorials of J2EE (if you opt that) from lot of sites. tutorialspoint.com or vogealla.de or mkyong.com